# How to Convert a string containing escaped JSON to object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a JSON received from a third part, which I can't change. 
This JSON has a property with special characters

```
"CryptoKey":"dqwe`fqer]OS@xMKA^Qd[3123ddFjqr412_hRHBXTfNEyp\lVLoia",
```

So, when I try to deserialize it, I receive the following error:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Bad JSON escape sequence: \l. Path '['148/FOEConfiguration'].CryptoKey', line 7, position 75.'

What I'm doing is:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(configFile);
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
```

Is there a way to deserialize this to an object without breaking it?
Or I'll have to read in a diferent way?

Comment: That's just not valid JSON at the moment. I suspect you'd be best off talking to whoever is providing the JSON and explaining that it's broken. It will be affecting everyone who uses it.

Comment: if json contain special char, it will be escape with double " to avoid this type of error. take a [look](http://www.json.org/) of json standard ```A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I just wanted to know if there is a way to avoid talking to them, because it would take longer

Comment: You definitely do want to be talking to them -- people who can't get the little things right are likely to not get the big things right either. If they're serializing JSON by using buggy or self-made serializers that violate the specs, you probably don't want them handling anything called `CryptoKey` either. If you preprocessed the string on your end in the assumption that they'll never fix this bug, you'll be in for a rude surprise if someone else complains to them and they do.

Comment: It wouldn't be pretty, but you could escape the invalid \ via `var hack = invalidJson.Replace("\\", "\\\\")` and deserialize the new string.

Comment: @Nico: the danger in this is twofold: 1) it won't work for strings that contain other invalid sequences because the producer isn't escaping (like a `"`), if there are any; 2) it will mangle the string silently if the producer ever fixes the bug and does start escaping. Implementing "fixes" like this is a bad idea if you can't detect for sure when the fix should no longer apply, because things can start breaking without any sign that they're broken. There is no unambiguous way to "re-escape" the string properly in all cases, so "fixing it" may just compound one bug with another.

Comment: @JeroenMostert very true, so the "solution" should only be used if there is absolutely no other way. Like you and others said, the only good approach is to fix the JSON on the producer side.

Comment: Thanks everyone!